# Maximizing an equation given a constraint

Tags: calculus

How do you maximize $A=xy^2$ given the constrain $x^2 + y^2 = 3$. $x$ and $y$ are both positive, what are values of $x$ and $y$ that maximize $A$ and the maximum value of $A$.

I don't know how to do this problem, if you can give an explaining , that would be decent. This is a question out of curiousty, not a homework assignment.

Comment: By x2 do you mean 2x?

Comment: i was changing it, its x^2 + y^2

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are a great way to do this. For future readers, I wanted to note that Lagrange multipliers require some knowledge of multivariable calculus (albeit not much).

Comment: Yes just brush up on partial derivatives and you're pretty much good to go :)

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{\rm A}\left(x\right) = 3x - x^{3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

First not that the constraint set $C = \{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 = 3 \}$ is compact, hence the continuous function $A$ has a maximum.

You can use Lagrange multipliers, or note that you can write $y^2 = 3-x^2$, where $x \in [-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}]$. The problem them becomes
$\max_{x \in [-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}]} 3x-x^3$. Note that the cost is non constant and is zero at $x=\pm \sqrt{3}$, hence the maximum occurs in $(-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3})$ (an open set).

If we differentiate and look for zeros of the derivative, we get $x = \pm 1$, and checking values shows that $x=1$ is the maximizer, with maximum value 2.

Answer (score 0):

A simple substitution argument will now suffice. Set $y^{2} = 3 - x^{2}$, and substitute. So $A = x(3-x^{2})$. Could you maximize $A$ now?

Comment: how? do you maximize it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the first derivative test? Where does $\frac{dA}{dx} = 0$? Once you find the critical points, you will want to test that $A$ changes from an increasing to a decreasing function around each critical point.

Comment: so x = 0? or x = sqrt(3)?

Comment: Make sure to differentiate first. You want the zeros of $3 - 3x^{2}$.

Comment: You need to be careful. The function $A$ in the answer above is unbounded above (let $ x \to -\infty$). You need to take the constraints into account when you do the substitution.